# 2001 Buick Regal LS 3.8L - Cannot identify two wire connector near alternator

Tags: electrical, buick, connector, regal

**What is the two wire connector located in the upper left side of the picture below (near alternator with blue band) for a 2001 Buick Regal LS 3.8L 3800 Series II?**

It is about three inches long. The closest electrical components are the alternator, O2 sensor, and fuel injectors, but they are already connected and I cannot find any female connectors that are missing plugs.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are there any trouble codes (CEL)?

Comment: Is there an issue with the vehicle, or have you just noticed this unconnected plug?  It may be a generic wiring harness that has connectors that are not used on your version of the vehicle.

Comment: What are the colors on the wires going to the connector?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Both wires are dark pink, one of which also has a black line.

Comment: @HandyHowie The car is running poorly but I suspect that is not related to this electrical connector. The car was running poorly due to a clogged exhaust. I replaced everything from the exhaust manifold back. The engine is still running poorly with a P0401 code. Replaced EGR valve, same issue. I suspect I have a bad exhaust manifold/gasket.